# Remove double quotes in json encode result(PHP)

Tags: json

Need to escape double quotes from some of strings in json encode results

example:

```
$test= 'loreum';
$id=1;
if($test!=''){
   $test='null';
}
```

$response= array('id'=>$id ,'name'=> $test);

Sample output

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "null", 
}
```

I need output like this

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": null, 
}
```

Thankz in Advance man

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
if($test!=''){
   $test=null; //notice the missing quotes here
}
```

Comment: Actually maybe use another variable for that. Don't reuse $test like I did.